# How to store all array values into a single React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I have a config file which contains an array that gets data from redux

```
"datapath": [
  "common.registration.rgsnInfoRs[0].value",  // street name
  "common.registration.rgsnInfoRs[1].value",  // city
  "common.registration.rgsnInfoRs[2].value",  // state
  "common.registration.rgsnInfoRs[3].value"   // zip code
]
```

In my react component, when I tried to render the data from this array it only returns back the data for the zip code. How can I make my component render all of index data in my render method?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    // data: '',
    data: []
  }
}
componentDidMount(){
  if(_.get(this.props, 'datapath')){
    _.map(this.props.datapath, (item, i) => {
      let data=_.get(this.props.state,`i`);
      this.setState({data})
    })
  }
}

// static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
//   if(_.get(props, 'datapath')){
//     _.map(props.datapath, (item, i) => {
//       let data=_.get(props.state,item);
//       state.data = data;
//     }) 
//   }
// }


static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if(_.get(props, 'datapath')){
      _.map(props.datapath, (item, i) => {
        let data=_.get(props.state,item);
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return { data: [...prevState.data, data] }
         });
      })
    }
  }

render() {
  const {type, label} = this.props;
  return (
    type === "grid" ? (
      <Grid.Column style={style}>
        <strong>{label ? `${label}:` : null}</strong> {this.state.data}
      </Grid.Column>
    ) : (
      null
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype for `this.props.state`?

Comment: @fyasir thanks for the response. The data type for the state was in string but I changed it to an array. I'll update my post with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not asking the right questions.  It is generally a bad idea to store data from props in state because it can lead to stale and outdated data.  If you can already access it from props, then you don't need to *also* have it in state.

Your component receive a prop `state` which is an object and a prop `datapath` which is an array of paths used to access properties on that `state`.  This is already weird and you should look into better patterns for accessing redux data through selector functions.

But if we can't change that, we can at least change this component. You can convert an array of paths to an array of values with one line of code:

```
const data = this.props.datapath.map( path => _.get(this.props.state, path) );
```

All of the state and lifecycle in your component is unnecessary.  It could be reduced to this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { type, label = "", state, datapath = [] } = this.props;
    const data = datapath.map((path) => _.get(state, path, ''));
    return type === "grid" ? (
      <Grid.Column style={style}>
        <strong>{label}</strong> {data.join(", ")}
      </Grid.Column>
    ) : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial data type for `this.state.data` is an array. But in the following line, it gets the value of the item (in this case, it's either street name, city, state or zipcode). These values are string type and override the `this.state.data` datatype from array to string.

```
let data=_.get(props.state, `i`); // This is incorrect
```

You should append the value in the state data instead of assign in `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
  if(_.get(this.props, 'datapath')){
    _.map(this.props.datapath, (item, i) => {
       let data=_.get(this.props.state,`i`);
       this.setState((prevState) => {
          return { data: [...prevState.data, data] }
        });
    })
  }
}
```

Now Let's look at `getDerivedStateFromProps` function. This is a static function and you can not use `this` inside a static function. According to the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), this function returns the updated state.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
const newData = [];
if(_.get(props, 'datapath')) {
  _.map(props.datapath, (item, i) => {
    let data=_.get(props.state,item);
    newData.push(data);
  });
  return { data: newData };
}
```

}

Comment: That didn't work. It's breaking the page. Am I putting in the right place?
`static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if(_.get(props, 'datapath')){
      _.map(props.datapath, (item, i) => {
        let data=_.get(props.state,item);
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return { data: [...prevState.data + data] }
         });
      })
    }
  }`

Comment: let me also add it to the post for better visiblity.

Comment: @Shaun what's the error do you get in the console?

Comment: I see the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Comment: you are trying to use this.setState in a static function :)  in the `getDerivedStateFromProps ` you should return the state instead of using this.setState

Answer (score 0):

I think, when you are looping through the data and setting the state you are overriding the old data present in the state already.

may be you will have to include the previous data as well as set new data in it something like this.

```
this.setState({data : [...this.state.data, data]})
```

Comment: I tried the above line but that didn't work. It's breaking the page.